# Restriction of locally free sheaf associated projective modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, toric-geometry

My question comes from the paper of Tamafumi's "On Equivariant Vector Bundles On An Almost Homogeneous Variety" (it can be downloaded freely in [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-57/issue-none/On-equivariant-vector-bundles-on-an-almost-homogeneous-variety/nmj/1118795362.full)).

> **Question 1**
> Let $X = X(\Delta)$ be a toric variety with $\Delta$ being a complete fan. Let $\sigma$ be a maximal cone. And $\mathcal(E)$ a locally free sheave over $X$. Tamafumi said that then $E|_{U_{\sigma}}$ is associated to a projective $A_{\sigma}$-module. Why?

I know free module must be projective. But locally free sheaf depends on the open cover. Who can tell me why $E|_{U_{\sigma}}$ is associated to a projective $A_{\sigma}$-module?

Thank you very much!

> **Question 2**
> In the Theorem 3.5., this theorem required $M$ to be a projctive $A_{\sigma}$-module of **"rank $r$"**. I can't understand the meaning of **"rank $r$"**. Does it mean that $M$ is a direct summand of a free $A_{\sigma}$-module of rank $r$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the notation. Is $U_\sigma$ an affine open subset isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} A_\sigma$?

Comment: @Daniel just so you're aware, this question is 10 years old and the asker has not visited the site for at least 6 years. The reason it was edited and bumped today was for replacement of a dead link.

Comment: For future users coming across this question, assuming $U_\alpha\cong\operatorname{Spec} A_\alpha$, the first duplicate explains how a locally free sheaf on $U_\alpha$ corresponds to a projective module over $A_\alpha$ and the second duplicate explains various definitions of the rank of a coherent sheaf.